# How to validate the transition of a java object from one state to another[both states are user defined]?

Tags: java

I have a java object which can transition to different states defined by the user. But those transitions should happen in an order. What are the ways I can validate the state change?

States:

Wakeup,
Get Ready,
Work,
Eat,
Sleep

The object can have the following states but it should follow the order. The object can go from wakeup to get ready but not to work.

I tried using HashMaps and Arrays, but not sure which is the efficient and proper way to validate this using Java programming

I thought about using Hashmaps like below.

```
HashMap<String, String> stateMap = new HashMap<>();
stateMap.put("Wakeup", "get REady");
stateMap.put("get Ready", "Work");
```

and validate the change.

But this has one more challenge, in my actual problem the object can go from one state to more than one state and all are valid. So I am stuck here thinking which is the right way to do this in Java?

Comment: That's a very broad question. A few considerations - have you thought about defining an Enum for your states so that you can define your Map in a type-safe (and typo-safe) way rather than with a String? And if you can transition to more than one state and you want to use a Map, than you can use `Map<State, Set<State>>`.

Comment: However you do it, you validate it by testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum like this:

```
public enum State {
    WAKE_UP(Set.of(1)),
    GET_READY(Set.of(2)),
    WORK(Set.of(3, 4)), //multiple valid next states
    EAT(Set.of(4)),
    SLEEP(Set.of(0));

    private Set<Integer> validNextStates;

    State(Set<Integer> validNextStates) {
        this.validNextStates = validNextStates;
    }

    public Set<State> getValidNextStates() {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(state -> validNextStates.contains(state.ordinal()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public boolean isValidNextState(State nextState) {
        return getValidNextStates().contains(nextState);
    }
}
```

And then validate like so:

```
System.out.println(State.GET_READY.isValidNextState(State.WORK));
System.out.println(State.GET_READY.isValidNextState(State.EAT));
```

**Output**

```
true
false
```